# Optional parameters "must be a compile-time constant"

Tags: c#, .net

I have a class divided in two partial files, like this:

```
public partial class PersonRepository : BaseRepository<Person>
{
    public static readonly string ColumnID = "ID";
    ...
```

and

```
public partial class PersonRepository : BaseRepository<Person>
{
    public List<Person> GetByCompany(int companyID, string sortExpression = ColumnID)
    {
    ...
```

But the compiler keeps saying that `sortExpression` "must be a compile-time constant". To me it seems a perfect compile-time constant, so I don't understand where the problem is.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

No, the expression `PersonRespository.ColumnID` is not classified as a compile-time constant. The expression "ID" is, but that's not what you're using as the default parameter.

In particular, if `ColumnID` is "just a normal field" then any references to it will be resolved *as* a field - so if you compile an assembly which refers to the field, then change the value and rebuild the assembly containing `PersonRepository`, the referring assembly *will* see that change.

If you change your declaration to:

```
 public const string ColumnID = "ID";
```

then it *is* a compile-time constant expression. That means in our previous scenario, the value of the constant is baked into any code that refers to it - and changing the value later without recompiling that referring code *won't* change the value used by that referring code.

See section 7.19 of the C# 4 language specification for more details about what counts as a constant expression.

Comment: Thank you! Can you explain me why my expression is not a compile-time constant?

Comment: @Alessandro: All `const` members are implicitly static.

Comment: Ok, but If I have `readonly ColumnID` in the same assembly as `GetByCompany` than how is it different from `const ColumID`? I still need to recompile referenced assembly to get the change, right? Also, I can always write `...string sortExpression = null) { sortExpression = sortExpression ??  ColumnID;...` The idea of variable default parameter seem to be nice future. Is it considered, a bad practice or is it disallowed just because some technical nuances?

Comment: @PawełAudionysos: It's different because the value can't be baked into each use of it, which is true for a `const` expression.

Comment: @PawełAudionysos: Using null as a default value that's then replaced by a potentially non-constant value is a reasonable pattern, yes. But Stack Overflow comments aren't intended to be used for questions like this.

Answer (score 7):

You must declare your `ColumnID` as `const`.

The `static readonly` string will be instantiated when the class is first accessed in your code, and you could also initialize it with the return value of a static method, so it's not a compile-time constant for the compiler (even if in this case it obviously is for a person reading the code).

Answer (score 5):

const is something declared with const keyword.

readonly field can be assigned in constructor and its not compile time constant.
the code that you've written right now runs in initializer (before constructor).
const fields are 'baked' in as constants.

Answer (score 5):

change

```
public static readonly string ColumnID = "ID";
```

to

```
public const string ColumnID = "ID";
```

Answer (score 5):

> `readonly`

The value of a `readonly` field *can* be changed (in a constructor). You need a `const`.

Answer (score 4):

Try to change this

```
public static readonly string ColumnID = "ID";
```

to

```
public const string ColumnID = "ID";
```

Answer (score 3):

Just for completeness, here are the three valid default values for an optional argument: ( from: [MSDN: Named and Optional Arguments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx))

1. a constant expression
2. an expression of the form `new ValType()`, where `ValType` is a value type, 
   such as an `enum` or a `struct`; (note: only the parameterless constructor can be used)
3. an expression of the form `default(ValType)`, where `ValType` is a value type.

Answer (score 2):

```
public const string ColumnID = "ID";
```