# Optional parameters “must be a compile-time constant”

Tags: c#, c++-cli, constants, default-value

I have a similar problem the issue described in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7672005/optional-parameters-must-be-a-compile-time-constant)
In my case however the optional param default values is:
1. Defined in a separate C++/CLI dll.
2. Is already defined in that lib as "public static const"
When I try to use the value as a default parameter value from C# I get "must be a compile time constant".
Is there a way to share a common const value between (C++/cli) library and (C#) app?

C++/CLI lib:

```
namespace MyCPlusPlusCLILib {
    public ref class CPPCLIClass {
    public:
       static const double Invalid = -1;
}
```

C# code:

```
public MyMethod(double fish = MyCPlusPlusCLILib.CPPCLIClass.Invalid) { }
// C# compiler error "Must be a compile time const"
```

OR

```
const double MyConstDouble = MyCPlusPlusCLILib.CPPCLIClass.Invalid;
// C# compiler error "Must be a compile time const"
```

Comment: What type is the parameter?

Comment: Post some code please.

Comment: I suppose it should be `const` instead of `static const`

Comment: @close voter: please clarify your close vote.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: In C# const => static - is this the case for C++?  I dont think so. I.e in C# const can be accessed as static but in C++ that is not the case so I think it really needs to be static there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The *const* keyword in C++ declares constants that are not all that const, it can be arbitrarily cast away with a const_cast<>.

You'll need to use a C++/CLI specific keyword to declare a .NET constant, the kind whose value is stored in the metadata but doesn't also have underlying storage.  Use the *literal* keyword:

```
    literal double Invalid = -1;
```

Which solves your problem, the C# compiler is happy with that one.  Do note the iffiness of public constants.  Your C# compiler will compile the value into the generated IL directly, substituting "Invalid" with the literal value.  This will turn out poorly when you update your C++/CLI assembly with a bug fix that changes the literal but don't recompile the C# code.  Public constants are okay for manifest constants, like Math::Pi.

Comment: const, readonly, literal... spoiled for choice.  This is indeed the solution I was looking for.  Iffiness understood and accepted in this instance (C++ code is build of firmware code - not going to change in a hurry).  Thanks.

Comment: No, you can't use `const_cast` to remove `const` from an object declared `const`.  C# `const` is more akin to C++ `constexpr`.  C++ `const`, used on an object (not the target type of a pointer or reference) means that the value cannot change after initialization, however that initial (and permanent) value can be computed from run-time variables.  C++ `const` (again, on an object, not the target type of a handle) corresponds to immutability.

Answer (score 1):

`MyCPlusPlusCLILib.CPPCLIClass.Invalid` is not a compile-time constant, because you could put in a different version of `MyCPlusPlusCLILib`, with `Invalid` set to a different value.

If you don't want to make the default value for the C# method an explicit `-1`, you could do something like this: Pick a different value for a C# default, and when you get that, substitute in the C++/CLI `Invalid`.

```
public void MyMethod(double fish = Double.NaN)
{
    if (Double.IsNaN(fish))
        fish = MyCPlusPlusCLILib.CPPCLIClass.Invalid;

    ...
}
```

Comment: So is there any solution to this.  I would like to share a single Invalid value between C++/Cli and C# code - is that possible?

Comment: See edit. It's not possible to share the value directly, but you can use one default value to trigger use of another.

Comment: This is a solution +1 - and I think Im correct in thinking it doesn't suffer ifiness of Hans solution - in that if lib is updated old sharp code will still pull new lib value from lib.  But in this particular case I can live with ifiness and literal is cleaner.  Thanks.